# auto pass param to res.render nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Says I want to exclude or include layout param into my routes but I have more than 50 routes, I have to do this to every single res.render.

```
if(req.headers['something']){
  res.render('index',{'layout':false})
}else{
  res.render('index')
}
```

It's a pain when some of the route I have to pass other param. Is there any way I can use middleware to solve this problem?

```
router.use(function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.headers['something']);
   // if true auto add layout object to every single res.render()
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) variable to make `layout` available in all templates

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
  if ( req.headers['something'] ) {
      res.locals.layout = false;
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: It should be, `router.use` cathes all requests, and adding to `res.locals` should make the variable available in all the commonly used templating engines etc.